# Can I open a discussion thread on Math.SE?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

As written in my title, I wanna ask an opinionated question on Math.SE, but I am not sure if this is okay. So I have this kind of meta-question.

Sincerely,

Comment: No, the main math.se site is not designed for discussions; it is a question and answer site, and seeking answers which are ultimately opinion-based, gives users an obvious reason to vote to close such a question.  Consider positing your question in one of the math.se chatrooms, which allow for discussions.

Comment: See [Math.se chatrooms](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=math.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I was not well aware of that.

Comment: No problem!  It was good for you to check that out, here, first. :-)

Comment: There are some related discussion - I will add a caveat that they are quite old and the site has evolved since then. (Maybe somebody will be lucky enough to finding something more recent.) Here you go: [What kinds of soft questions are acceptable at math.stackexchange?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/17483), [What are some examples of good questions falling under the tags (soft-question), (advice), (career-development)?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/22121) and maybe also [Are career related questions allowed?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/19609)

Comment: The chatrooms seem to be an under-advertised resource.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Technically, yes, you can. Whether or not it will get closed very quickly, amass downvotes, deletion votes, and ultimately be weighed against you when the time comes to face the algorithm's decision to limit your questions, as well as possible suspensions if you keep creating these sort of discussions... well, that's up to you.

This is a common mistake, calling this site a *forum*. Forums are meant to facilitate discussion. This is a Q&A site, it is meant to have questions and answers to these questions. Yes, we have the comments where we can have a modicum of discussion, but those are really meant like salt and pepper: it's not the main course, it's just something to flavour your meal.

## Please avoid lengthy discussions on the main site, and do not open questions with the sole purpose of a discussion about opinions.